# How do I open a file using Atom on WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, atom

I am trying to open a file using Atom from bash on Windows. So what I did was I added an alias in my ***.bash_profile*** like this:

```
alias atom="/mnt/c/Users/Mido/AppData/Local/atom/atom.exe"
```

So let's say I am on my Desktop and I try opening a file called ***index.html*** by using: `atom index.html`. What this actually does is it creates a new file called *index.html* in the directory where *atom.exe* is located. Weirdly enough, I followed the exact same procedure for Sublime text, and when I do `subl index.html`, I am getting the file that I want. Why is this not working with Atom?

Comment: Atom for Windows doesn't work in bash for Windows. Kinda obvious but sometimes people need to be reminded of obvious things.

Comment: Use the full path of that file.

Comment: Hey Biswapriyo I tried doing that it didn't do it

Answer (score 0):

I found that when calling atom.exe from within wsl, the path is not interpreted correctly and defaults to atom.exe's path. In Windows, your wsl path starts with "\wsl$" which is the issue. You can use a drive map in Windows to get around this. I mapped "Z:" to "\wsl$\Ubuntu" and can open files from bash now with `atom "Z:\home\user\index.html"` for instance.

Further aliasing or scripting using pwd could make this less cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Installing atom from within bash worked for me. Just installed it for linux as per the guidelines [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-linux):

```
wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```

After this you can use atom as you normally would. This will not be the windows native atom installation but will be installed as a separate linux program.